# adding classes to multiple elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, random

i'm a novice to jquery and i'm trying to do the following:

i've got multiple instances of a div. to each instance i randomly add a class (for changing some attributes). the added classes are taken from a list.

this works well — but now i'm trying to additionally add the same (random) class to a child-div of the previous.

my html is:

```
<div class="random">
    <div class="alsorandom"> </div>
</div>

<div class="random">
    <div class="alsorandom"> </div>
</div>
```

here's my current jquery (the randomization takes place so that 2 classes are never added after one another):

```
var classes = ['blue', 'yellow', 'lightorange', 'violet', 'green'];
var prevClass = "";
$('.randomcolor').each(function() {
    var classes2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if (classes[i] !== prevClass) {
            classes2.push(classes[i]);
        }
    }
    $(this).addClass(prevClass = classes2[Math.floor(Math.random()*classes2.length)]);
});
```

the following i have tried and it doesn't work:

```
$('.randomcolor, .alsorandom').each(function() { ...
```

i'd be gracious for any help. thank you.

Comment: The supposed working example does nothing > http://jsfiddle.net/vYL55/

Comment: where is the `.randomcolor` element? without that class this will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the additional element is a direct descendant of the first element, you can use the `.children()` method to get it. Like this:

```
prevClass = classes2[Math.floor(Math.random()*classes2.length)];
$(this).addClass(prevClass).children('.alsorandom').addClass(prevClass);
```

The entire code would look like this:

```
var classes = ['blue', 'yellow', 'lightorange', 'violet', 'green'];
var prevClass = "";
$('.randomcolor').each(function() {
    var classes2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if (classes[i] !== prevClass) {
            classes2.push(classes[i]);
        }
    }
    prevClass = classes2[Math.floor(Math.random()*classes2.length)];
    $(this).addClass(prevClass).children('.alsorandom').addClass(prevClass);
});
```

If the additional element is a descendant, but not necessarily a direct descendant, then use the `.find()` method instead of the `.children()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your html, instead of this:

```
$('.randomcolor, .alsorandom')
```

do this:

```
$('.random, .alsorandom')
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/vYL55/2/

Cheers

Comment: i put down the wrong class in the example.. sorry, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery .each() like this:

```
var classes = ["blue", "red", "green"];

$(".random").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var classIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*(classes.length));
    alert(classIndex);
    $this.addClass(classes[classIndex]);
});
```

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sousatg/9TUF9/) with a working example

Comment: mh, i dont get this — sorry. i see alerts & my former functionality of 2 random addclasses not appearing after one another doesn't work anymore.